# Concurrency in resolving an array of promises

Tags: javascript, concurrency, es6-promise

So basically I found that promises would resolve concurrently when you create an array of promises and deal with **individual promises** in a loop... But it doesn't work when you create individual promises and deal with them in a loop...

So basically this question comes from me playing with axios and I originally thought this was a bug (https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1973). However I soon discovered it was actually a problem with misunderstanding some part of Promise, especially `await Promise`. However I don't think I could find anything in the MDN document unless I have missed something.

This will **not work**:

```js
let results = [];
for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('foo');
        }, 10000);
    })
    results.push(await promise);
}
```

But this **will**:

```js
let results = [];

const promises = [
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('foo');
        }, 10000);
    }),
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('foo');
        }, 10000);
    }),
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('foo');
        }, 10000);
    }),
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('foo');
        }, 10000);
    }),
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('foo');
        }, 10000);
    }),
];

for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    results.push(await promises[i-1]);
}
```

I would expect, in both cases, that the array of promises (`results`) to resolve in a concurrent manner.

However in the first example, the promises actually resolve one after another.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I was just being silly...

The first case, we are creating five individual promises through loops, of course we have to wait until one resolves before executing the second loop.

The second case, we are creating the array of promises first, so they start running concurrently. When we loop through 5 of them, we would actually be blocked at the first loop until the first promise resolves, the rest 4 loops would then finish at no time (because the rest 4 promises will be resolved).

This is just because 5 promises are running concurrently in the array.